# Converter páginas de documento PDF para JPGs

Tags: linux, bash, revisão-de-código

O seguinte código encontra-se a funcionar dentro do pretendido, onde o mesmo recebe parâmetros de forma a proceder à conversão de todas as páginas de um ficheiro PDF em ficheiros JPG:

- ID ([número natural](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_natural))
- Caminho absoluto (tem que existir e apontar para ficheiro PDF)
- utilizador do sistema (tem que existir)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Collect parameters values into human readable variables
id="$1"
filenamepath="$2"
owner="$3"

# check the ID
if [ -z "$id" ]; then
    echo "Parâmetro #1 deverá conter o ID da base de dados! Nada foi recebido."
    exit 0
else
    if ! (expr "$id" + 0  > /dev/null 2>&1 && [ "$id" -gt 0 ]); then
        echo "Parâmetro #1 deverá ser um inteiro!"
        exit 0
    fi
fi

# check the file
if [ -z "$filenamepath" ]; then
    echo "Parâmetro #2 deverá conter o caminho completo e nome do PDF a processar! Nada foi recebido."
    exit 0
else
    if [ ! -f "$filenamepath" ]; then
        echo "O ficheiro indicado não existe no servidor, confira o caminho e o nome do ficheiro!"
        exit 0
    fi
fi

# check the owner
if [ -z "$owner" ]; then
    echo "Parâmetro #3 deverá conter o nome do proprietário dos ficheiros a gerar."
    exit 0
else
    if ! id -u "$owner" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "O nome de utilizador indicado não existe no sistema, confira os dados!"
        exit 0
    fi
fi

# All good, lets work

# Set the filename and the filepath 
filename=$(basename $filenamepath)
filepath=${filenamepath%/*}

# Give some feedback to the user
echo "A iniciar trabalhos com o ficheiro $filename"

# create directory if it does not exist
if [ ! -d "$filepath/$id" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$filepath/$id"
    chown "$owner:$owner" "$filepath/$id"
else
    echo "A diretoria de destino já existe, vou terminar assumindo que o documento já está convertido!";
    exit 1
fi

# copy the file into the target directory
cp "$filenamepath" "$filepath/$id/$filename"
chown "$owner:$owner" "$filepath/$id/$filename"

# go to the target directory
cd "$filepath/$id/"

# convert the PDF pages into .ppm files
pdftoppm "$filepath/$id/$filename" tmp

# convert each .ppm file into a .jpg file
# The .jpg files will have 800px of height with a proportional width
# The .jpg files will have a quality of 80%
ls -1 *.ppm | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'convert "$0" -resize x800 -quality 80% "${0%.*}.jpg"'

chown "$owner:$owner" *

# remove .ppm files
rm -rf *.ppm

# remove the .pdf file
rm -rf "$filename"

# Inform the user that the job is completed
echo "Concluído!"

exit 1
```

A sua utilização pode ser realizada da seguinte forma:

```
#sh ./meuScript 15 /caminho/para/documento/nome.pdf utilizador
      └───────┘ └┘ └──────────────────────────────┘ └────────┘
      ↓         ↓                ↓                      ↓
     nome do    ID    caminho absoluto para PDF      nome do utilizador
     script                                          para permissões da
                                                     pasta e ficheiro
```

Que vai originar a saída:

```
A iniciar trabalhos com o ficheiro nome.pdf
Concluído!
```

## Pergunta

Para o que foi descrito, o processo está a decorrer de forma eficiente ou o mesmo pode ser simplificado?

Answer (score 1):

A script está optima e se cumpre a função, mais que óptima.

Ainda assim, se lhe fores mexer, uma direção possivel é pôr o `pdftoppm` a converter
e fazer `scale` directamente, ou seja algo como:

```
 mkdir $id
 pdftoppm -jpeg -scale-to  800  $filename  $id/tmp
```

(Cuidado que não estou a preservar os detalhes... = precisas de os acertar)

Comment: Esse foi o conceito inicial, mas em CentOS o `pdftoppm` não tem o parâmetro `-jpg` nem `-jpeg` (?!?) Não entendi ainda porque, daí ter seguido para usar o `convert` para transformar os `.PPM` resultantes do `pdftoppm` em `.JPG`. Representa trabalho adicional, mas funciona e continua compatível com diversos sistemas. De qualquer forma, o `-scale-to` não havia explorado, vou experimentar! :)

Comment: Claro; é possivel que seja questão de versões (o centos costuma ser mais conservador que o fedora) a minha versão é `pdftoppm -v
pdftoppm version 0.18.1
Copyright 2005-2011 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2004 Glyph & Cog, LLC`